# How to correctly validate form with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

So I have this jQuery for my form:

```
frm.submit(function(event) {

  validateForm();

  if(validateForm()) {
    $(this).submit();
    } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

});
```

It does sort of work, but I get JS `<error>` (and it doesn't say anything else in the console about it), I think the reason is that the function has to go through the validation again? Kind of like a circular dependency.

Can you show me a better way to do the exact thing that I'm trying to achieve here please?

1. Validate and show errors if filled in the wrong way;
2. Submit the form if everything is ok

Comment: There's a jquery form validation plugin that handles a lot of this for you!  http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

HTML -

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="tel" id="phone" />
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="errors"></div>
```

JS -

```
const user = {}

$('#submit').click(function(){
    // validating form

    if(!$('#name').val()) {
        $('#errors').text('invalid value in "name" field')
        return;
    }    

    if(!$('#phone').val()) {
        $('#errors').text('invalid value in "phone" field')
        return;
    }

    $('#errors').text('');
    user.phone = $('#phone').val();
    user.name = $('#name').val();

    // form submission goes here 
});
```

### Logic -

Once a function returns, the execution of anything else after the `return` expression itself, is prevented.

If you don't `return` anything, the interpreter will continue to the next expression.

This gives you the option of manipulating elements and handle errors just before returning and stopping the function from continuing to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm(){
 if (input.val().isok && select.val().ispresent){
   form.submit();
 }else{
  show_errors();
 }
}
```

why not that way?

Comment: At which moment do you call this function?

Comment: on button.click + keydown (enter)